# How do you pass a multi dimensional array from view to controller?

Tags: php, arrays, parameter-passing

It was easy passing data from controller to view. Also, to pass data from view to controller you need form tags. But, how do you pass an array from an input form? any idea guys? here's what the array looks like:

```
$test = array
(
array($employee_id[0],$name[0],$days_worked[0],$overtime_hours[0]),
array($employee_id[1],$name[1],$days_worked[1],$overtime_hours[1]),
array($employee_id[2],$name[2],$days_worked[2],$overtime_hours[2])
);
```

and from my html view i got here an input form:

```
<input name="test" type="text" class="form-control" id="test" value="<?php echo $test;?>">
```

and when i got to my model to test if it gotten the data inside the array:

```
$this->test = $_POST['test'];
echo $test = $_POST['test'];
```

all i got was a String "Array". I can't access what's inside the array. I need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your questions is unclear.. you want to pass the array to you view, or to the HTML output into the INPUT element? 
These are 2 different things, as one is only passing an array internally in you application (on the server), and the second is passing it into you form data, displaying it in the browser, and then sending the form to the server and getting the data there.

For the first - i see no problem there, as passing variables is no issue
The second - it is not possible by default to pass a multi-dimensional array into a form input. Becasue the input has only 1 dimension. 
You could pass the data with some conversion function e.g. as a JSON string

```
 value="<?php echo json_encode($test);?>"
```

and then load it like this:

```
   $this->test = json_decode($_POST['test']);
```

But that does not make sense in the frontend I guess, as the user would not understant what data is presented in the input field.

To to it in a logical way, I would divide the data into groups, and then display accordingly in more input fields e.g.

```
 <input name="test[0][employee_id]" type="text" class="form-control" id="test" value="<?php echo $test[0][0];?>">
 <input name="test[0][employee_name]" type="text" class="form-control" id="test" value="<?php echo $test[0][1];?>">
 <input name="test[0][employee_days_worked]" type="text" class="form-control" id="test" value="<?php echo $test[0][2]?>">
 <input name="test[0][employee_overtime]" type="text" class="form-control" id="test" value="<?php echo $test[0][3];?>">
```

but do it more nicely. This way you can create sth which will be sent as a multi-dim. array to the php script.

as suggested in another answer here, you can see the structure with var_dump($test)

Answer (score 1):

Array values cant be passed in form data directly.
You should use json_encode. 
In your view file

```
   $encoded_text =  echo json_encode($test);
 <input name="test" type="text" class="form-control" id="test" value="<?php echo $encoded_text ;?>">
```

Now in your model just decode this

`$test = json_decode($test, $assoc = TRUE);`

Answer (score 1):

If you use serialize() on your controller and unserialize() on the view you should be able to access it in the same way. I believe that's what you're asking.